# Close chrome from bat file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I am trying to kill chrome from bat file. Tried

```
TASKKILL /IM chrome.exe /F
```

but it doesnt close the chrome. What is the correct way to do that ?

Comment: Does it work if you leave off the /F?  Taskkill without /F sends a WM_CLOSE first, and gives the app a chance to act properly (such as shutting down child processes).  With /F, it does a TerminateProcess, which doesn't let the app do anything before closing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You'll want to use the same command, but with the /T argument, like so:

```
taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe /T
```

The /T argument kills the process and all of its child processes. Effectively, it should close all processes with the same process name that you provide in the argument list.

If you'd like to suppress errors/output, pipe the ouput to nul, like this:

```
taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe /T > nul
```

Regardless of the method you use, you must run the batch file as an Administrator to kill the chrome.exe processes.

Here's an explanation of what the other command flags mean:

- /F: force the process to terminate without cleaning up or waiting
- /IM: name of the process to be terminated
- /T: terminate the process and all child processes

Comment: well it kills chrome but when i open chrome again it is showing restore pages i dont want that

Answer (score 6):

**taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe /T**

or

**taskkill /F /IM chrome* /T**

{Explanation:

taskkill (to kill the processes),

/F (forcefully terminate the process),

/IM (Image Name of the process to be terminated. '*' wildcard can be sure to specify all the tasks or image names)

/T (Terminate all child of the image or process) )

Answer (score 2):

this code is working in my script well:

```
taskkill /f /im chrome.exe /fi "username eq domain\user.name"
```

Comment: Please explain why the command in the question does not work and why your command does work.

Comment: Im running script as **administrator** and filtering process to kill by user name. Maybe this are the reasons.

Answer (score 2):

This works great for me:

```
taskkill /IM chrome.exe
```

Close Google Chrome but after when you reopen the software leaves the opened tabs just like last time.

Answer (score 0):

As a healthier approach for the browser, I've developed a code that will first attempt to close windows for 50 times. After 50 attempts, it will terminate the task. This way, Google Chrome can be closed more reliably. After 50 attempts, it will wait for 1 second and then kill the chrome.exe process. This reduces the chances of seeing the prompt "Chrome didn't shut down correctly. Restore pages?"

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

: Google Chrome
set "CloseBrowserAttemptCount=0"
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq chrome.exe" /fo table /nh') do (
    if !CloseBrowserAttemptCount! LSS 50 (
        powershell -Command "Get-Process chrome | ForEach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() }" > nul 2> nul
    )
    set /a "CloseBrowserAttemptCount+=1"
)
timeout /nobreak /t 1 > nul 2> nul
taskkill -f -im chrome.exe > nul 2> nul

pause
```