# How to close all Chrome browser using MATLAB command line?

Tags: matlab, google-chrome

I am trying to automate my computer and I want to add a function to close my Chrome browser. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Use `system` but the argument will depend on the operating system

**Windows**

```
system('taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe')
```

**Linux**

```
system('wmctrl -c chrome')
```

**OSX**

```
system('killall Google\ Chrome')
```

Sources: [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412976/close-chrome-from-bat-file), [Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34101/exit-google-chrome-from-terminal), [OSX](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158684/chrome-wont-quit-mac-yosemite)